# Replacing words in text that match regex

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace all words in my text that match a give regex. I have made a function that looks like this:

```
    const str   = this.node.body;
    const regex = /(href=\')([^\']*)(\')/g;
    let newStr;

    if (str.match(regex)) {
      for(let i = 0; i < str.match(regex).length; i++) {
        let url = str.match(regex)[i] + ' target="_blank"';
        newStr = str.replace(str.match(regex)[i], url);
      }
    }
```

But, this is not right, since only the last value of the matching string will be replaced in the `newStr`, since in the loop is always taking the text from the str variable, how can I make it so that I loop through updated `newStr`, and replace all the values that match `regex`?

Comment: I think this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine

Look at [String.prototype.replace definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
const str   = this.node.body;
const regex = /(href=\')([^\']*)(\')/g;
let newStr = str.replace(/(href=\')([^\']*)(\')/g, '$& target="_blank"')
```